# Query color of a window's title bar in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, sdl-2, kde-plasma

I am writing a small GUI in SDL2. Is there a simple way to query the system's default color theme used to decorate application windows on Linux (debian 11, KDE plasma)?

Comment: Wouldn't it be different for each Linux distro? Linux alone has no "color theme" (unless terminal color customization counts), every distro has its desktop environment.

Comment: Yes, I should have worded that better! I was wondering if there was a way to query a desktop environment's "color pallet," or "theme." I don't know how different each DE is, but sometimes there seems to be overlap in system configuration on Linux.